# Is there any advantage of having sub domains

Tags: webserver

i would like to know is there any advantage of having sub domains.I am doing a site which is having many sub domains. ie, for each part they are keeping a server. And the server is very slow. Is there any way to increase the speed of my site? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be the alternative? I assume you're thinking of subdomains vs. subdirectories in a webserver. The only thing that you can do to subdomains (and not subdirectories) is putting them in your DNS service and assign different IP adresses for every subdomain, along with other DNS records.
Technically, depending on your webserver and besides the DNS thing, you can do everything with subdirectories what you can do with subdomains and vice versa. It's just a matter of your webserver configuration.